# Joining SQL result with string

Tags: sql

I have a MSSQL 2005 database with a lot of records that were added since last backup. I want to make another SQL script that puts result values into string representing INSERT statement that I will save for later use.
Something like:

```
SELECT 'Insert INTO tabname columns VALUES("+Column1"',')' FROM XY
```

Or simple example:

```
Column A,Row1=5

SELECT A+"BLAH" FROM X
```

should return "BLAH5"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand, if you want to build a script (lets say PHP) just run over the records and either print out or to file something like:

```
echo 'INSERT INTO tablename (field1,field2) VALUES('.$row['field1'].','.$row['field2'].');';
```

if you want that string in the result directly from the SQL you could use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO...VALUES(',field1,',',field2,')') FROM yourtable;
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

You should really mention what SQL database system you're using.

For MySQL, what you want is [the CONCAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

```
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES ("', column1, '");') FROM xy;
```

Answer (score 0):

what version of sql?
for ms sql, you can use + for concatenation and single quotes for strings

for mysql/oracle, use concat(column, 'string')